# Add CSS Class to YADCF Select2 Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2, yadcf

I have a yadcf Select2 filter that looks like this:

```
{column_number : 1, filter_type: "select", select_type: "select2", style_class: "subjectFilter"}
```

I used `style_class` to add a CSS class called `subjectFilter`. This class shows up in the DOM, and it is attached to the `select` box. However, the actual `select2` dropdown doesn't obey the style (i.e. width) of the `select` box. Is it possible to add a class to the `<span>` tag that holds the `.select-container` class?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the select2 container you can use the [`select_type_options`](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/933e77c612bf33f68933cb4413b4c3650929ed51/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L216) attribute,

Here is an usage example:

`{
    column_number : 2,
    select_type: 'select2',
    select_type_options: {width: '150px', minimumResultsForSearch: -1}
 }`